# Cant retrieve x-death header in rabbit listener springboot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am using rabbit mq and I want to access the message retries but I always get a null reading x-death value as displayed in this example. However the message is read correctly.

```
@Component
@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue")
public class AdyenNotificationMessageListener {

  @RabbitHandler
  public void processMessage(byte[] messageByte, @Header(name = "x-death", required = false) Map<?, ?> death) {
    // death is always null
  }

}
```

Using `springboot version : '2.4.1'` with `spring-boot-starter-amqp'`

Aany hint of what I maybe doing wrong would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me; are you sure the message has the header?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So68231711Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So68231711Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable("so68231711")
                .deadLetterExchange("")
                .deadLetterRoutingKey("so68231711.dlq")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Queue dlq() {
        return new Queue("so68231711.dlq");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so68231711")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("toDLQ");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so68231711.dlq")
    public void listenDlq(String in, @Header(name = "x-death", required=false) Map<?, ?> death) {
        System.out.println(in);
        System.out.println(death);
    }

}
```

```
foo
... Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

...

foo
{reason=rejected, count=1, exchange=, time=Tue Jul 06 11:09:30 EDT 2021, routing-keys=[so68231711], queue=so68231711}
```